# Is product of continuous function subspace of continuous function on $[0,1]×[0,1]$?

Tags: vector-spaces

Consider V be a vector space of all continuous function on $[0,1]×[0,1]$.
Let F be the collection of all functions defined on (x,y) belonging to $[0,1]×[0,1]$ of form $f_1(x)f_2(y)$ where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous function defined on $[0,1]$.
Is F is a subspace of V?

My approach.
I have show that sum of product of two contionus function will be continuous on this domain. I beleive this gonna be subspace. Trying to make it in this form, but unable to do it.

Comment: Try to show that it is not closed under addition.

Comment: Are you saying me to find an counter example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supose $(x)(1)+(1)(y)=f(x)g(y)$. Then, $0+y=f(0)g(y)$. If $f(0)=0$ we get a  contradiction immediately. Otherwise, we get $g(y)=cy$ where $c=\
\frac 1 {f(0)}$.

Similarly, $x+0=f(x)g(0)$ gives $f(x)=dx$ where $d=\frac 1 {g(0)}$. Finally we get $x+y=f(x)g(y)=cdxy$. Put $y=x$ to get $2x=cdx^{2}$. Can you get a contradiction now?